# how to update an attribute by passing generic variable through body parameter using expressjs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I'm creating a restful API for blog application.
I have to update an attribute of a blog using postman. The object in the database of which an attribute has to be updated looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5a5306a9432f7b12f6e77a21",
    "title": "new article",
    "_author": {
        "username": "linuxuser"
    },
    "content": "content of the article goes here",
    "__v": 0,
    "createdAt": "2018-01-08T05:48:41.683Z"
}
```

I may have to update any attribute but I cannot address it in code dynamically.

Here's the code:

```
put('/updateblog', function(req, res) {
    db.blogModel.findById(req.query.id, function(err, blog) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        blog.title = req.body.title;
        // here instead to title i have to update the attribute which is passed through body parameter

        blog.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({
                message: "blog updated"
            });
        });
    });
});`
```

here instead of updating title, I want to update an attribute which is passed through body parameter. I do not know what client is going to send, so, I'm looking for more generic code.
For instance, a user sent a put request to update `content` attribute, then how do I write code so that corresponding attribute is updated rather than the title like in the above code.

Comment: both key and value passed in the req? If yes what is the key name?

Comment: yeah, both the key and value are passed in the req. For example consider this: { "content": "new content" }  This is sent through postman app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the keys from `req.body` and iterate or if `req.body` will contain only the user updated key & value of **existing fields** in your collection, you can directly use that as update object, but prefer to use some path like `req.body.userUpdate` for user's updates.

```
var updateObject = {};
for ( var key in req.body ) { //add logic to filter non existing fields
    updateObject[key] = req.body[key] //change path if required
}
```

once update object has been created use `findByIdAndUpdate` to update

```
findByIdAndUpdate(req.query.id, {$set : updateObject } , function(err, blog ) {...}
```

in mongo CLI

```
> db.x.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : "5a5306a9432f7b12f6e77a21",
    "title" : "new article",
    "_author" : {
        "username" : "linuxuser"
    },
    "content" : "content of the article goes here",
    "__v" : 0,
    "createdAt" : "2018-01-08T05:48:41.683Z"
}
```

update object

```
> var mod = {}
> mod['content']='new content'
new content
```

update

```
> db.x.update({"_id": "5a5306a9432f7b12f6e77a21"}, {$set : mod}, {$upsert:false})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

output

```
> db.x.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : "5a5306a9432f7b12f6e77a21",
    "title" : "new article",
    "_author" : {
        "username" : "linuxuser"
    },
    "content" : "new content",
    "__v" : 0,
    "createdAt" : "2018-01-08T05:48:41.683Z"
}
>
```